# Giving precedence to AND and OR operators inside the Pandas.query() method?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following toy data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['BMW', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Buick', 'Toyota', 'Ford', 'Buick'],
                          'Metric':['Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator', 'Indicator'],
                          'Dimension':['Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Long', 'Short', 'Short', 'Long', 'Long'],
                          'User': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Japan', 'USA', 'USA', 'Russia'],
                          'Sales':[500, 3000, 2500, 200, 50, 1000, 9000, 5000],
                          'Expenses':[20, 50, 70, 90, 10, 3, 100, 100],
                          'Rebate':[1, 26, 90, 87, 100, 1000, 14, 90]
                   })
```

I have the following script that prompts the user for some input and then returns a filtered output:

```
user_input_sales = float(raw_input('Enter a value to filter Sales:  '))
user_input_expenses = float(raw_input('Enter a value to filter Expenses:  '))
user_input_rebates = float(raw_input('Enter a value to filter Rebates:  '))

subset_df = df.query('Sales > @user_input_sales or Expenses > @user_input_expenses')

print(subset_df)
```

This works fine.  But, now I would like to be able to query as follows:

```
subset_df = df_query(('Sales > @user_input_sales or Expenses > @user_input_expenses')) AND ('Rebates > @ user_input_rebates')
```

**Notice the use of parentheses to give precedence to the OR and AND operators.**

I can't seem to make this work (syntactically).  The documentation on the .query() method doesn't show this case.

Does anyone see where the syntax is incorrect?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything in `DataFrame.query` must be a complete string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to query as follows:

```
df.query('(Sales > @user_input_sales OR Expenses > @user_input_expenses)'
         'AND (Rebate > @user_input_rebates)')
```

Comment: Worth mentioning (for readers) that this is a single condition (not multiple), but split across multiple strings (that are concatenated by the interpreter).